# MODX Ограничить количество товаров при добавлении в корзину

Tags: modx

в магазине у товара есть несколько размеров, как сделать так чтобы в корзину можно было положить максимум 3 в не зависимости от того какой размер выбран и какой товар, то есть если у одного товара выбран какой-то размер в количестве 2, то другого размера этого же товар или другой можно было положить в корзину только 1.

Answer (score 0):

Можно стилями/скриптами ограничить поле выбора количества товара, а также поиграть системными настройками (если вы используете minishop2, впрочем, это верно и для других ecommerce решений).

Посмотрите еще здесь: https://modx.pro/help/12060